# making things not a function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to organize my paypal revenue information by copying it into a google spreadsheet.

However, paypal writes my payments as "=+ $16.00USD" and it can not be read in google because it thinks its a function giving me an "#ERROR~"

How would I go back solving this without manually editing all the numbers.

Comment: @pnuts: Why not retag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert the string into currency IN EXCEL, copy the values into a worksheet and in the next column enter the following formula:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"=+ $",""),"USD",""),CHAR(34),""))
```

IF you are trying to use Google Spreadsheet, submit a new question with Google spreadsheet and not excel as the tags.

Comment: Clearly this question is about google spreadsheet, not Excel, thus it is mistagged. Next  time, just hit the "edit" button to submit an edit of the tags. I did it this time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you count this as "manual editing" but selecting the cells, Edit, Find and Replace..., Find `=+`, check *Also search within formulae*, <kbd>Done</kbd> should remove the `#ERROR!` message.

You might want to do something similar for `$` and `USD` if to process the value/s in some way.